# very simple loop in F#

Tags: f#

I tried this in both FSI and VS2010.Both gives the same output.

```
for i= 8 to 10 do
    for j=7 to 10 do
    let product=i*j
    printfn "%d * %o = %x" i j product
```

and the output is:

```
8*7=38
8*10=40
8*11=48
8*12=50
9*7=3f
9*10=48
9*11=51
9*12=5a
10*7=46
10*10=50
10*11=5a
10*12=64
val it : unit = ()
```

Am i missing something here?

I try to learn programming (with F# because I loved it) with online tutorials.

Comment: There are some excellent online books out there about learning to program. I would find and read them instead of trying to learn to program through "tutorials". Tutorials with not teach you how to program, though they are generally useful for tips and tricks. Unfortunately, I don't think you'll find many good teaching resources that use F# since it's a new language. You might want to look at the Scheme books that are out there, though.

Comment: The Scheme books I'm thinking of: http://mitpress.mit.edu/SICP/ and http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/ --
I suggest these not because I think Scheme is the perfect teaching language (though some people do think this), but because these well-known books for learning it are available online for free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You're missing something. 10(decimal) * 10 (octal) = 50 (hex). %d means decimal, %o means octal, and %x means hexidecimal. If you don't know what they are, google them.

The following are all the same statement.

In decimal:

10 * 8 = 80.

in octal:

12 * 10 = 120

in hex:

a * 8 = 50.

Please look closely at something before you copy it.

Comment: Was that last comment really needed?

Answer (score 12):

The output seems correct to me, since you are formatting the output of `i`, `j` and `product` in decimal (`%d`), octal (`%o`) and hex (`%x`), respectively.

The numbers 7, 8, 9 and 10 are being formatted as 7, 10, 11, and 12 because that is their octal representation. Change them all to `%d` or `%i` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Guess it's about the formatting string of `printfn`. Just try `%i`.

```
for i = 8 to 10 do
    for j = 7 to 10 do
        let product=i*j
        printfn "%i * %i = %i" i j product
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Hope people doesn't mind such simple questions!

Comment: That last identifier should be `%i`, not `i%`

Answer (score 0):

Note that the docs on printf format specifiers are here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370560(VS.100).aspx

(though as of today, the formatting of the document is a little messed up, making it hard to read)